# Failed to initialize GPU device #0: unknown error

Tags: windows-10, gpu, cuda

Each time I run the fit method for keras model, I got "...loss: nan - val_loss: nan"

**System configuration:**
windows 10
*tensorflow*           1.13.1
*Keras*                2.2.4

*GPU settings:*
*Type:*              NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
*Driver version:*    25.21.14.1881
*cuda toolkit file:* cuda_10.0.130_411.31_win10.exe
*CUPTI file:*        cupti-win64-cuda10-1.0.7.zip
*cuDNN SDK file:*  cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.1.zip

**Error details:**
[Failed to initialize GPU device #0: unknown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i58ol.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by changing the way the CUDA orders the devices. I'm not entirely sure why this worked. For python, you can do this with:

```
import os

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
```

I am using an mx150(1D10), which is the 10 series equivalent of the 940mx listed in your screenshot